# How to get source of function when toSource() and toString() return "[native code]" (using mozilla firefox)

Tags: javascript, mozilla

I am building a mozilla extension, and one of the tasks is to get the source code of js functions in a school website. I tried using .toSource() and .toString(), which both produced vague answers as shown below.

```
function click() {
    [native code]
}
```

Is there any work around to decompile the native code into readable javascript code? To be more specific, the function when called eventually does a GET request with information valuable to my project. My goal is to look through the code and access that information from the function without having to have the website change view and page to the GET request. I did look at other stack overflow questions, but I was unable to find any way to make a workaround. Thanks for all advice!

Comment: You need to go to the Mozilla Code Base to get that info, Mozilla is written in C++ so you would still need to convert that over to javascript if you wanted to recreate the function in javascript.  Hope that helps. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Introduction

Comment: Okay, in that case, would there be a better way of scraping a website where the links don't contain any get request information and yet seem to be the only way of getting the desired information?

Comment: do you have an example of the website?

Comment: It is a website portal for students at a college. Unfortunately, I don't think I could let people look at it unless they were enrolled at the college.